# Text editor which enables real-time spell checking

Tags: notepad++, spell-check

Is there a text editor which enables real-time spell checking like the rich tech editor in Gmail or even typing anything using Firefox? is there a Notepad++ plugin?

Answer (score 1):

There is an inline "live" spell check in the newest version of Notepad++ as per this question: [How can one turn off spell checking in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/593312/how-can-one-turn-off-spell-checking-in-notepad).

If it is not already activated, you can do it three ways:

1. When installing; during the Choose components selection navigate to "Plugins" and check the "Spell-checker"-plugin.
2. In Notepad++ locate "Plugins" > "DSpellCheck" > "Auto-check document" or alternatively press the key combo Alt+A.
3. In v6.5 there is a toolbar button (ABC with a squiggly line under it) which enable/disables the function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's not compatible right now with the latest version of Notepad++

http://squiggly.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> combo to toggle spell check in [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).