# How can one turn off spell checking in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ recently added built-in support for spell checking, and it is enabled by default.

Where can I turn it off?

Comment: Turning off SP that only marks misspellings might be a nuisance.  However separately, I do **not expect or want to automatically change spellings without notice or permission**.  This often changes the meaning itself, without notice.  Your phone does, but in NP++ there's no easy way to prevent the changes without asking for your explicit permission before making changes.  There are **two separate settings**,

Answer (score 257, accepted):

You can do this in one of four ways.

1. When installing; during the Choose components selection navigate to "Plugins" and uncheck the "Spell-checker" plugin.
2. In Notepad++ locate "Plugins" > "DSpellCheck" > "Auto-check document"
3. Alternatively for no 2, press the key combo <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
4. Press the toolbar button labeled DS or ABC (from version 6.5)

Comment: In the version I'm running v6.4.5 there's also a toolbar button to toggle it ("DS" with the squiggly underline)

Comment: v6.5 has now changed the toolbar button to appear as ABC with a squiggly underline under it.

Comment: Before 2,3,4. Plugins > Plugin Manager > Available tab > check DSpellCheck > **Install**

Answer (score 37):

You can click the "DS" or the [image: [1]] button (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) to turn Spell-Check off/on easily:

[image: DS button in the toolbar]

Answer (score 20):

The instructions are right on the download page:

> If it does bother you, just uncheck Menu item Auto-check Document
>   (Menu: Plugins -> DSpellCheck -> Auto-check Document).

[Source](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.3.3-release.html)

Answer (score 10):

There are **TWO Settings** that are independent of each other: **Auto-Correct/Completion** and **Spell-Check**.  "Auto-Correct" can inadvertently change what you intended to write, while "Spell-Check" just independently and automatically marks misspellings.

To change **AUTO-CORRECT/COMPLETION:**
-- Go to **Settings...  Preferences...**
-- Then, on the left pane, (under the "Backup" section), go to 
**"AUTO-COMPLETION" section:**
-- Simply **UN-check** this choice.  (No NPP++ restart required)
This does not turn off spell checking, so you will still see misspelled words marked with a red underline.

To change **SPELL-CHECK:**
Simply toggle the [image: Button with ABC and a ~~~ as an underline, on the toolbar], (or the DS button in older versions.) **NOTE: This will NOT change the "Auto-Correct/Completion" setting.** (This [image: k] icon will not show up for me when "big icons" are chosen, only "standard icons".  Also, couldn't find the Alt+A as a shortcut, either.  YMMV, but at least it is still under the Plugins/DSSpell menu as an option, assuming you've enabled menus as visible.)

No, you are not alone.... This "Auto-Correct/Completion" problem really "bugged" me until today.

In the January 2015 version 6.7.4, by default, "Spell-Checking" now does a lot more than just "check" spelling.   Auto-Correct/Completion has been driving me mad, occasionally fixing my "spelling" for things like precise links that now no longer work, which I didn't notice were changed, until they failed.

NP++ Devs:  Thanks for all your work, but I'd suggest putting an on/off on the toolbar for both Auto-Correct/Completion and Spell-Check, and I'd suggest that you turn Auto-Correct/Completion off by default.  Also, in preferences, call it "spell-checking" so we can find it, and allow me to change both settings under one place.  If that means that there are two places in the UI or prefs, then allow me to change both settings, both places, where it is obvious there are two separate settings.  Please clarify that Auto-Correct is a synonym for Auto-Completion, (which is the most annoying problem), in addition to Spell-Check, (which merely marks misspelling).

Comment: upvoting this answer since it's helpful for those like me who search "spell check" while actually meaning "auto completion"

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to disable the spell check suggestion icon which gets displayed on the misspelled word then

1. Go to `Plugins | DSpellCheck | Settings`
2. At the bottom of the page, you will find setting `Suggestions Control`
3. You can change it to `Use N++ Context Menu` - this will disable the `Special Suggestion` button which gets displayed by default.

Please note that this won't disable the spell check, but the interface of spell check suggestions is changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable this in the plugin's configuration file, on my Windows 2008 server using Notepad++ v6.5.5 it is in

C:\Users\lessthanideal\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config\DSpellCheck.ini

By default this file does not exist.  When you disable spellchecking in the interface with the menus by unticking "Plugins" > "DSpellCheck" > "Auto-check document", the file gets created containing these lines:

```
[SpellCheck]
Autocheck=0
```

So you can just create the file with those contents yourself.  Useful if you are deploying the tool and automatically installing it across many machines.