# How can one turn off spellchecking in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, user-interface, spell-check, autocorrect

I have 6.8.3; the solutions given here:

[How can one turn off spell checking in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/593312/how-can-one-turn-off-spell-checking-in-notepad)

... are for version 6.5 or so.  The UI items mentioned in the solution are no longer present.

That is, my toolbar doesn't have an ABC button, nor do the Plugins nor Settings -> Backup have any way to disable Auto-Correct.  I *do* see the DSpellchecking plugin but do not see any way to configure it.

I am one of the authors of Working Software's Lookup and Spellswell; bad spellers drive me totally round the bend.  (They were originally written by Mike Green and Dave Johnson, I developed new versions.)

Comment: The plugin was not installed.

Comment: The DSpellchecking NOT installed but there IS auto-correct.  This leads me to speculate that Auto-Correct is a different thing from whatever DSpellcheck does.

Comment: If I can't find a way to disable Auto-Correct I'll have to use some other text editor.  For now I've got CodeWarrior but really I would prefer Notepad++ without the Auto-Correct.

Comment: There is no Tools menu, but there is a Plugins menu.  In the Installed pane, there is no spell-checker item.

Comment: OK - DavidPostill - disabling "Word Completion" under Settings->Preferences->Auto-Completion does the trick.  Thanks!  If you post that as an Answer - as opposed to a comment - I'll accept it as the solution to my problem, thereby kicking you some Reputation.

Comment: I tried all three options - Function Completion, Word Completion, Function and Word Completion.  ALL of them are _profoundly_ disruptive; I don't want _completion_ but it would be helpful to be notified if I misspelled a word, then - and only then - to have the _option_ to ask Notepad++ to display some suggestions.  I never, ever use function completion in any development tool; IMHO that makes one a lazy, inattentive coder.

Comment: Comments converted to an answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I turn off spellchecking in Notepad++?

There are three places where spell checking can occur.

1. **Auto-completion**.

   To disable go to menu > "Settings" > "Preferences" > "Auto-Completion" and uncheck "Enable auto-completion on each input".
2. **DSpellCheck plugin**.

   To disable go to menu > "Plugins" > "DSpellCheck" and uncheck "Spell Check Document Automatically" or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
3. **SpellChecker plugin**.

   This is not automatic, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to perform the spell check. You can also remove the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

1. Plugins > DSpellCheck
2. Uncheck the box "Spell Check Document Automatically"

Comment: Nope.  Just now I realized that DSpellcheck is not even installed.  Note that I'm using version _6.8.3_.  I think your instructions apply to a previous revision.  It appears that Auto-Correct is now built-in and no longer a function of the DSpellcheck Plugin.