# Printing without spelling errors underline in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, printing, spell-check

**tl;dr**: Is there any way to print document in Notepad++ without spelling errors underline and without [disabling spell checking](https://superuser.com/a/593315/156554) in the same time?

---

I have my Notepad++ set to English and I'm doing most things in English as well. Sometimes I write documents in other languages and because I don't have proper dictionary installed texts in editor look like a one long, straight line of red curly underlines.

I'm pretty fine with that however, I'm not fine with the fact that Notepad++ prints those underlines (this time straight, not curly) when printing documents.

Is there any way to disable spell checking in Notepad++ just when printing, but keep it enabled when editing documents (I don't want to [disable it permanently](https://superuser.com/a/593315/156554)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, as far as I can see there is no such option (though it might be useful).

If there were such an option, it would be in the [Print settings](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Printing_And_Exporting) ("Settings" / "Print"). There are options to print line numbers, to change the colors and to add headers/footers. However, there is nothing to control printing of spelling error underlines.

The only workaround I can see is to disable spell checking before you print, as you noted. There is a keyboard shortcut to toggle this, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. If you press that before printing (and afterwards, to re-enable), you solve the problem with two keystrokes.

---

If you feel that feature could be useful for others, too, consider writing a ticket to request it. NotePad++ issues are tracked on GitHub, project [notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus); consider posting an issue there.

Comment: Perfect (detailed and concise) answer and perfect (fast and easy) solution: Alt+A / Ctrl+P / Enter / Alt+A. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, next to *sleske*'s one, is to install additional dictionaries and then set *Plugins* > *DSpellCheck* > *Settings...* > *Language* to `Multiple Languages...`:

[image]

However, as warned, using too many languages will most likely slow down your Notepad++.