# How do I enable spell checking in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, spell-check

[This question from 4 years ago](https://superuser.com/questions/593312/how-can-one-turn-off-spell-checking-in-notepad) claims that Notepad++ has spell checking enabled by default. This doesn't seem to be the case anymore, as I haven't been able to find any sign of a spell check option in Notepad++ v7.5.1.

How can I re-enable spell checking in Notepad++?

Answer (score 51):

1. Install the [Plugin Manager](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases) if you do not have it already
2. **Install DSpellCheck**: Plugins --> Plugins Admin:

   - (check the box for [DSpellCheck](https://github.com/Predelnik/DSpellCheck/releases))
   - <kbd>Install</kbd>
3. Restart Notepad++ (if necessary)
4. **Download dictionaries**: Plugins --> DSpellCheck --> Settings:

   - Library: `Hunspell`
   - <kbd>Download...</kbd> (check boxes for your dictionaries, <kbd>Install Selected</kbd>)
   - Language: (select your language)
5. <kbd>OK</kbd>
6. Restart Notepad++ (if necessary)

[image: DSpellCheck settings, dictionary download]

Turn automatic spell check on and off with the red-squiggle ABC button [image: Spell Check button] in the toolbar.

Comment: That doesn't work for me - the list of available dictionaries is empty.

Comment: ahh yes, that did it. Bizarre, that NP++ is such a great program but just adding spellcheck is a bit obscure.

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks! Looking for grammar as well. I asked the question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1590966/spelling-and-grammar-check-for-notepad

Comment: thanks for the answer. Between steps 4 and 5, while attempting to start downloading the dictionary, NPP crashes in my case (running Windows 10)

Comment: Using the "Windows" option, instead of "Hunspell" worked for me in Windows 10, DSpellCheck version 1.4.17.0

Comment: Needed #4 here! I've installed this plugin in the past, but this time I forgot that you have to explicitly download a dictionary after that!

Answer (score 9):

Install [DSpellCheck](https://github.com/Predelnik/DSpellCheck/releases) plugin.

Here is how to,

1. Goto: Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin manager
2. Select DSpellCheck from Available plugin list
3. Click Install and let notepadd++ restart
4. Goto: Plugins -> DSpellCheck -> Change Current Language
5. Select your language(s) and add

Answer (score 5):

There are several spell checkers available as plug-ins to Notepad++.  You can add them via the Plugin Manager or manually by downloading them from the [resources page](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/resources/) and then extracting them to your Notepad++ install folder.

It seems the original default spell check was removed due to it [occasionally causing crashes with Windows 10](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/427).  The original spell check function was 
[DSpellCheck](https://github.com/Predelnik/DSpellCheck/releases).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  I certainly can't get spell check working after reading this answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link http://aspell.net/win32/ and download and install both files `Full installer` and the precompiled dictionary for English `aspell-en-<VERSION>.exe` (or any other available language). Now you can access the spell checker from the menu `Plugins > Spell-Checker > Spell-Checker...` (If Spell-Checker plugin does not show up on the menu, install it by using the Plugin Manager).

Answer (score 0):

Update to @techturtle's answer:
It is added back as per this [thread](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3739). I also checked and tested this by installing latest version of Notepad++(v7.6.2). And now the answer to [question from 4 year ago](https://superuser.com/a/593315/979451) is working.

Answer (score 0):

check the video here
open notepad++ go to plugins admin> search for dspell and add the appropriate language for which you will be using dictionary - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjErNd8XWUw

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1134956)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Plugin Manager is called Plugin Admin and you check the box for DSpellCheck and click Install. You get US English.

Doesn't know some words, like "arbitered" or "minorly", so it's not like it's Merriam. But if you're confident and just want to catch the occasional mistype (as opposed to misspell), it's OK.

Looks like you can change the language later, bunch of options that make no sense to language experts. I know 3 well enough to call false squiggles. In general, the world is waiting for the awesome spell checker, but since billion corporations can't, I guess we have to wait until devs call for the help of dictionary publishers.

Wanted to share an updated answer and what to expect/rely on.