# Spelling AND Grammar check for Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, spell-check, grammar

This site provided with spellcheck for Notepad ++ html/markup spellcheck, but not grammar:
[How do I enable spell checking in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/1262046/how-do-i-enable-spell-checking-in-notepad)

Looking to do spelling and grammar check on html all in one option via notepad ++. Where can I find that?

Comment: notepad++ is a text editor, not a word processor. It does not have grammar checking and there are no plug-ins to do so.

Comment: @DavidPostill - That is correct; however, it would be very helpful to DIY webmasters to have a grammar check. It is quite laborious without it. There are most definitely some libraries out there that could be used to build a grammar check plugin...quite easily. I don't do that kind of programming, or I would do it myself. If someone wanted to develop it, I'd be happy to test it for them.

Comment: " If someone wanted to develop it, I'd be happy to test it for them." Off topic for [su]

Comment: @DavidPostill - Where should I post something like that? Happy to!

Comment: Not anywhere on the stackexchange network.

Comment: @DavidPostill - there should be! Why don't we create a place for this! :)